Append Global Text to Any/All Validation Error Messages in Backpack for Laravel
I need to append a standard error message or text (e.g., Please call 1-800 or email @ for assistance...) to the collection of validation error messages that occur in one of my Backpack for Laravel models. I'm using the standard Request file that Backpack creates. What's the best way to add/append an error message, text, etc. if any validation error occurs?

Backpack is using Laravel FormRequest, so i think you can override this class and customize the "failedValidation" method to achieve this.
Dont forget extend your Requests from custom FormRequest.
Cheers.
